# nfs: enabling file locking (flock)

Tags: nfs, locking

I'm having trouble finding really any information at all on how to make file locking work for NFS mounts, to resolve client errors like `ENOLCK (No locks available)`.

I understand that in NFSv3 file locking was handled by separate services, and in NFSv4 it is handled by the main protocol.

I thought it would be nice if we could consolidate the various scenarios and resolve this all in one place.  How do you enable file locking for NFS versions 3 and 4?

I'm personally on debian buster on a raspberry pi.  I set up NFS basically following the debian buster handbook, but I'm getting the "no locks available" error when I try to lock a file.

Comment: The short answer is, you don't use NFSv3 or other 1990s era antiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By starting `rpc.lockd` and `rpc.statd` daemons, or whatever alternatives your OS has for this.

P.S. and this has nothing to do witrh the NFS protocol version which mentioned in the first comment, lol (experts everywhere, eh ?).

Comment: It's great to get a reply.  on my debian buster system there is an rpc-statd service which is already running, but no rpc-lockd service available

Comment: Another thing is that you have to run these on the client, not on the server.:)

Comment: I needed to use systemctl to start and enable `rpc-statd` on both debian buster and redhat 7.  It would be good to add what these daemons do, so that people on homebrew linux systems can find quick answers.